# VB.NET Get text from textbox without a specific string

Tags: vb.net, string

How can I make something like in vb.net?
When Button 1 clicked:

```
Textbox1.text = "big banana"
dim string as string = "big"
MsgBox(Textbox1.Text without string)
```

Output: banana

Comment: msgbox(textbox1.text.replace(string, "").trim)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this. For example you have 2 textboxes the 1st one is the textbox that you will input the words you like and the second one is the textbox that you will use to remove a specific word in textbox1. Do something like this.

```
Dim StringToRemove as String = TextBox2.text
If Textbox1.Text.Contains(StringToRemove) then
Msgbox(TextBox1.Text.Replace(StringToRemove,"").Trim)
Else
Msgbox("The word you want to remove doesnt exist.")
End If
```

[image]

Sorry for the headers thats Sample 1 and Sample 2. At least you have a full working code with parameters with this one, checks if the word you want to remove exist.

Answer (score 1):

Just replace it

```
Textbox1.text = "big banana"
dim string1 as string = "big"
Msgbox(textbox1.Text.Replace(string1, "").Trim)
```